# How do you set a .properties file on Azure DevOps pipeline as some sort of environment variable?

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, properties-file

You see, I have connected my Android project in my Bitbucket repository into an Azure DevOps pipeline. The pipeline ran fine until I set a `apikeys.properties` file, which I put on `gitignore` because obviously, API keys are secret.

I ran my Android project through my app-level `build.gradle`. The project builds fine as long as I have said `properties` file in my local machine, and locally in the machines of my colleagues, under the usual conditions.

Making Azure DevOps's pipeline variables don't seem to work properly in my pipeline, secret or otherwise: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables.

[image: Adding variables in Azure DevOps pipeline]

There is another option, that of Kubernetes, but I am not sure how to proceed with this one: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

[image: Kubernetes?]

Or should I just abandon the pursuit of setting environment variables through `.properties` files?

Very much obliged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your title and the first screenshot, do you mean to use the `APPCENTER_DEV_KEY` secret variable as an environment variable in yaml ?  If yes, the first thing to be clear is that we should not set secret variables in the yaml file, we should set them in the pipeline editor using the web interface. From your screenshot, you have already done this.

Then, unlike normal variables, secret variables are not automatically decrypted as script environment variables. So we need to map them explicitly. As shown below:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(secretVariable)   

  # Using the mapped env var:
    Write-Host "This works: $env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"    # Recommended
```

This is mentioned in the variable document you posted in your issue. If I misunderstood the issue, please point it out, and it would be better to be clear in the case: why you put `.properties` file on `gitignore`, what effect you want to achieve, `'seemingly not work in the pipeline'` specifically refer to what.

Comment: Yep, didn't set any keys in my YAML file. Also, yes, I have set my variables in both my Pipeline Editor and in my System Environment Variables (i am using Windows). I'm currently exploring environment variables right now as there seems to be no way to incorporate my `secrets.properties` as a variable or a variable group.

Comment: You can try to parse the properties in the .properties file into json and then add them as variable groups using [Variablegroups-Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api.Set `"isSecret": true` in the request body.

Comment: I just ended up setting up system environment variables in both my local machine and my azure devops project, then removed the need to define and seek out my `secrets.properties` file, and pipeline ran fine. Thanks so much!

Comment: Congratulations! Glad to hear your problem solved. If my answer is helpful to you, you could accept it as an answer or you can  convert your solution into an answer and mark it. This could help other community members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.Have a nice day:)